# python dies on windows without stacktrace

Tags: python, windows, pandas, memory

I'm loading a large csv file into pandas and when I load too many lines at once I get a dialog box telling me "Python has stopped working" without any error messages in the terminal ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN1Zc.jpg)). I suspect it's a memory limitation but it'd be nice to confirm with the python stacktrace directly.  Anyone have a similar experience and know how to get at what's happening?

**update:** Turns out not to have been a memory limitation after all.  I think the root cause was a pandas issue, upgrading from 20.3 -> 22.0 seems to have fixed it.  I suspect it was related to this: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16798

Comment: Try enabling [faulthandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/faulthandler.html) in your script.

Answer (score 3):

Use the trace module to try and force it.

```
python -u -m trace -t program.py
```

or

```
python -m pdb program.py
```

Python debugger might also provide insight. If neither of these work, it's most likely a memory issue based on the context you provided.

Hope this helps.